# Highlight div that contains date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make code that changes the color of the div (with the class "carrythatweight") if it has the date in it.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="carrythateright">groan...</div>
<div class="carrythateright">what in the world is going on !!!</div>
<div class="carrythateright">stackoverflow is SO helpful. It is now 12/26/2012 !!!!</div>​
```

This is the script I'm using, but it doesn't really work:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".carrythatweight:contains('' + month + '/' + day + '/' + year +'')").css("color", "#00bbbb");
});​
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/37tR5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/37tR5/2/

Comment: Oh thanks, @JanDvorak ! What did you change to make it work?

Comment: @DumbProducts He fixed your quotes inside `:contains`. @JanDvorak You should post that as an answer.

Comment: WHY THE DOWNVOTE! It seems like lowering other people's reputation is the new thing on Stack Overflow... I hate it when people downvote questions without an explanation...

Comment: @DumbProducts: A person may downvote if they feel this question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful, just as the tooltip text says. I'm assuming the downvote was for one of those in that person's opinion and most likely not because it is a "new thing" to do. `lowering other people's reputation is the new thing on Stack Overflow`, seems a very strong statement. What statistics are you basing that on? If you are basing it on your -7 from your other question I would assume that -7 was for lack of research effort.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I don't think that this question is unclear, I believe it's quite the contrary. My point is that I don't think Stack Overflow users should downvote freely, (considering that it lowers the OP's hard-earned reputation, which some value quite a bit), and I think it's only good form to provide a reason to why the question's downvoted. After all, it's not all that hard to post a comment. Regarding "not showing any research effort", I don't believe my post falls into the "what have you tried" category, especially considering that I coded the stuff provided in the description.

Comment: @DumbProducts: If you have an issue with how SO works, the correct way to deal with that is to post any ideas for improving this system on SO meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ instead of claiming: `lowering other people's reputation is the new thing on Stack Overflow,` without at least showing a bunch of statistics backing that statement up. As said, post on SO-Meta if this is an issue for you how the current system works. Do a search on meta though first as this question may have already been asked on it.

Comment: I didn't downvote but to avoid them in the future:  1) Don't just write "this doesn't work".  Elaborate on how it doesn't work.  Wrong color/error messages/no action at all.  2) Double and triple-check for typos in your question.  `carrythateright` was right below `carrythatweight` in the paragraph.  Yes, they happen sometimes, but it makes it look like you are putting less effort into your own work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/37tR5/2/

I made two fixes in your code to make it work:

1) I replaced some single quotes with double quotes so that the selector gets interpolated as expected: Compare (original)

```
"...'' + month + '/' + day + '/' + year +'')"
```

with (fixed)

```
"...'" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year +"')"
```

2) I modified the class in the selector to match the class in the `div`s.

Comment: Thanks so much! (BTW the class selector matched the divs in my server, I just did that mistake on JsFiddle)

Comment: Yeah of course... unless someone would add a div with some date in the future... :D