# not :contains isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What did I do wrong? When I run this code, nothing is displayed.

The JavaScript code:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

$(".whocares:not(:contains('' + month + '/' + day + '/'+ year + ''))").remove();​
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="whocares">hi</div> <div class="whocares">12/26/2012 i like cake two</div> <div class="whocares">hi</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3gYU/)

Comment: It seems pretty obvious by looking at the syntax highlighting that the quotes are not correct.

Comment: Thank you, I got this working: jsfiddle.net/P3gYU/1

Comment: Now which answer do I select as correct???

Comment: @DumbProducts: How come the quotes where back to being wrong after you got them fixed in your last question in the same line? Seems weired and in this case a possible duplicate of it as the answers in both question address and fix the same issue   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046616/highlight-div-that-contains-date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. It should be something like this:

```
$(".whocares:not(:contains('" + month + "/" + day + "/"+ year+"'))").remove();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this is still not valid. raw text has to be surrounded in single quotes when using `:contains('some text')`.

Comment: @MatthewCox You are right, I corrected that, but it seems to work without the single quotes too.

Comment: @DumbProducts Go with Axel, he got it first and made the necessary correction. Climbing the low rep ladder is tough. =P

Comment: @axel.michel I have found different selectors that have still continued to work even when the jquery documentation specified the use of specific syntax. Don't want to do it though because when the team gets around to fixing the bug ... your code might no longer function properly if you migrated to the newest version of the library.

Comment: @MatthewCox Definitely agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are incorrect.

```
$(".whocares:not(:contains('" + month + '/' + day + '/'+ year + "'))").remove();​
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure you are escaping out of the string properly when trying to include variables. This works just fine if you use double quotes instead:

```
$(".whocares:not(:contains('" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "'))").remove();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```